# Laravel cannot be installed with php 8

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Hello I am going to create a project with laravel, I am using composer global installer, with the php version I am using is php 8.

but I have a problem when I do the laravel installation. What should I do?

Warning: require_once(phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Resources/mb_convert_variables.php8):

Failed to open stream: phar error: "vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Resources/mb_convert_variables.php8" is not a file in phar "C:/composer/composer.phar" in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php on line 115

I have tried to update composer but it doesn't work. Check out the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/update-composer-global-with-php8 gives a solution.

Comment: I have tried run composer global remove phpunit/phpunit to remove global Composer, but an error still Error : PHP Warning:  require_once(phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Resources/mb_convert_variables.php8): Failed to open stream: phar error: "vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Resources/mb_convert_variables.php8" is not a file in phar "C:/composer/composer.phar" in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php on line 115

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Global composer because some global packages that not update to php8 so remove it then run `composer global update`.

Comment: I have tried run : composer global remove phpunit/phpunit  to remove global Composer, but an error still Error : PHP Warning: require_once(phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Resources/mb_convert_variables.php8): Failed to open stream: phar error: "vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Resources/mb_convert_variables.php8" is not a file in phar "C:/composer/composer.phar" in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php on line 115

Comment: 1) Try using composer version 2.0.1 with php8..... 2)  Or you can try patching phars setup-php uses.